# WPF Form Loads very slow after adding SpellCheck.IsEnabled to a Control

Tags: wpf, spell-checking

So I have a mysterious issue where after I've added `SpellCheck.IsEnabled` to one of my controls the form that hosts this control takes upwards of 3 seconds to load. Remove the spell check attribute and the form loads instantly.

Just for reference, the following is the only place changed in the form:

```
<TextBox TextWrapping="Wrap" Height="100"
         Text="{Binding ActivePostMetadata.Abstract}" SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True" 
         IsEnabled="{Binding IsAbstractVisible}" 
                          />
```

With `SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"` the form's InitializeLayout takes ~3 seconds, without it the initialization is instant.

To make things even more odd: It happens only on my dev machine. When running the compiled application on another machine there's no problem with the form popping up instantly.

I suspect it has to do with a possible Windows issue of finding dictionaries, but I have no idea where to look.

Any ideas what could be going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, after a bit more research it looks like the problem is due to many **temporary** dictionary files registered here:

```
HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries
```

I had about 20 dictionaries registered in `tmpFiles` many of which don't exist. tmpFiles has a lot of files in it and likely the file lookup along with the 2 or 3 dictionaries there that are actually available caused the slow down. Not sure what's dumping temporary dictionaries there, but I removed all the temporary files from the listing (leaving in my case just the Word dictionary) and now the form loads quickly again.

More info on where dictionary info comes from and what ultimately let me find this comes from here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh869748(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I have the same speed issue as you saw, but I don't have the registry key at all. Under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling` I only have a `(Default)` key and an `Options` subfolder. Any idea where I might find it, or what else I can do to solve this issue? Thans

Comment: I am getting the same thing, and I don't have any registry entries under `HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling` as in, I have the Microsoft folder, but that doesn't contain the spelling folder. I was also witnessing this on one machine but not another.