# Enabling SpellCheck in WPF TextBox slows loading

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, spell-checking

I have multiple TextBoxes in my WPF windows. I've just enabled SpellCheck for all TextBoxes in my solution. I then noticed that when I now load a window, instead of taking 2-3 seconds, it can take up to a minute to load, with the UI freezing, and the widow showing as blank while it loads.

Interestingly, this only happens to me. My colleagues, who are using the same code base as me, don't seem to have this issue.

I've seen these 2 other posts with similar issues:

[WPF Form Loads very slow after adding SpellCheck.IsEnabled to a Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394790/wpf-form-loads-very-slow-after-adding-spellcheck-isenabled-to-a-control)

[Spelling with textboxes and custom dictionaries slowing down my application in C# WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264673/spelling-with-textboxes-and-custom-dictionaries-slowing-down-my-application-in-c)

I've tried to follow the suggestions to delete the extra Registry Keys in HKCU\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Spelling\Dictionaries. 
However I don't have a **Dictionaries** folder in that location. All I have is an **Options** folder there.

Is there any other place where these temporary dictionaries might be stored? Or does anyone have any other solutions?

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?

Comment: I'm using Windows 7

Comment: Does this happen if you run the .exe directly, or only when running in Visual Studio? I assume you're using VS by the way!

Comment: Good thought! When I run it through VS, (yes I am using VS), I have the slowness issue. However, when I run the solution from the .exe, I have no speed issues! Which seems to indicate that it's a VS thing, but I'm still not sure how to fix it.