# WPF TextBox typing slowness with spellcheck enabled on Windows 10

Tags: wpf, textbox, windows-10, spell-checking

We're seeing significant slowness while typing into a WPF TextBox that has SpellCheck enabled on Windows 10.  We see this with just a simple application containing a TextBox:

```
<Window x:Class="TestSpellCheck.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestSpellCheck"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="textBox" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" AcceptsReturn="True" 
                 HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
                 SpellCheck.IsEnabled="True"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

When I paste a section of text with a number of spelling errors (say, some Lorem Ipsum text), subsequent typing sees a lag of a few seconds between when I type a character and when it appears on the screen.  This doesn't happen if the text I paste doesn't have spelling errors, or if I do this on Windows 7.

It's similar to an issue discuss on GitHub: http://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3350

I've produced a video to try and show the problem.  I talk while typing words, so you can see the delay between when I'm typing and when the characters show up on the screen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndVBaN07Gf0

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spell check textbox in Win10 - Slow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34167463/spell-check-textbox-in-win10-slow)

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37264673/spelling-with-textboxes-and-custom-dictionaries-slowing-down-my-application-in-c and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46394790/wpf-form-loads-very-slow-after-adding-spellcheck-isenabled-to-a-control

Comment: I think that post is talking about slowness while loading.  I'm looking at slowness while typing, after the TextBox is loaded.

Comment: Actually, it's more like a problem I saw on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/wpf/issues/3350

Comment: It seems the main complaint relates to slow loading, but that doesn't mean that the issue doesn't extent to typing response as well. In any case, other than recognize that using the built-in spellcheck creates dependencies on the Windows spellcheck component, which comes with its own potential pitfalls to be careful of, it's not clear how to even reproduce your problem reliably, never mind provide an answer that would satisfy your concern.

Comment: I disabled Grammarly and the slowness is gone... just leaving the tip here